# Flexbox and the <header>, <main>, and <footer> tags

Tags: flexbox

I've read in a few places that when using flexbox, you should have all content in a `<header>`, `<main>` and `<footer>` tag for flexbox to work its magic. Is this true? Are these tags needed?

Answer (score 2):

No. See the [abstract](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abstract) of the spec:

> The specification describes a CSS box model optimized for user
>   interface design. In the flex layout model, the children of a flex
>   container can be laid out in any direction, and can “flex” their
>   sizes, either growing to fill unused space or shrinking to avoid
>   overflowing the parent. Both horizontal and vertical alignment of the
>   children can be easily manipulated. Nesting of these boxes (horizontal
>   inside vertical, or vertical inside horizontal) can be used to build
>   layouts in two dimensions.
>
> [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) is a language for describing the rendering of structured documents
>   (such as HTML and XML) on screen, on paper, in speech, etc.

Flexbox is part of CSS, which is a language independent of HTML. So saying it requires some HTML elements makes no sense.

Here you have a working example which doesn't use those elements:

```css
div { display: flex; }
span { border: 1px solid; }
span:nth-child(1) { flex-grow: 1; }
span:nth-child(2) { flex-grow: 2; }
span:nth-child(3) { flex-grow: 3; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
</div>
```